# What is the correct way of using Bluebird for Mongoose promises?

Tags: mongoose, bluebird

I've been reading documentaion and articles and everyone seems to describe a different way about using Mongoose and Bluebird together. Even the official Mongoose documentation [says something](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) and Bluebird documentaion says [another thing](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html).

According to Mongoose:

```js
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

According to Bluebird:

```js
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));
```

So to my understanding, if you pick the Mongoose way a sample query would be like:

```js
User.findById('someId')
    .then(function(){
        // do stuff
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        // handle error
    })
```

But also in Mongoose docs it says that:

> Mongoose queries are not promises. However, they do have a .then() function for yield and async/await. If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function.

So in this case, is `.then` above a promise or not?

If you go with Bluebird way:

```js
User.findById('someId')
    .execAsync()
    .then(function(){
        // do stuff
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        // handle error
    })
```

Or maybe even skip `execAsync()` and start with `findByIdAsync` instead.

Really confused with different documentaion. I'd appreciate if someone can shed some light into this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**From Bluebird doc**

```
Promise.promisifyAll(
    Object target,
    [Object {
        suffix: String="Async",
        multiArgs: boolean=false,
        filter: boolean function(String name, function func, Object target, boolean passesDefaultFilter),
        promisifier: function(function originalFunction, function defaultPromisifier)
    } options] ) -> Object
```

as you can see, by default, promisifyAll add suffix 'Asyns', so if you are using this way of promisification:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));
```

the async version of `User.findById` will be `User.findByIdAsync`

**what about mongoose.Promise**

then you use promise library like

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

built-in promise mechanism replaced by library: `query.exec().constructor` replaced by `require('bluebird')` so instead `.exec()` for return promise, you can use bluebird probabilities directly for mongoose queries like

```
User.findOne({}).then(function(user){
    // ..
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about if I go the Mongoose way? As I asked in my question, is `.then` a promise in that case or not? And is there a reason to choose one way over the other?

Answer (score 27):

Choose the Mongoose way:

```
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
```

That's because Mongoose *already* supports promises (besides also accepting callbacks); the above code just replaces Mongoose's own promise library ([`mpromise`](https://github.com/aheckmann/mpromise)) by Bluebird (which is probably faster, better tested, and has more utility functions available).

Bluebird's `promisify*()` is meant to allow code that doesn't *already* use promises (purely callback-based functions) to return promises.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This improves @stasovlas' s answer.

Comment: mongoose may be loaded and connections made in a number of places throughout a code-base. Which locations need `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');` ? I believe the Mongoose object is a singleton, but I had trouble getting this change to take effect across a large project.

Comment: @MarkStosberg doing it once should be enough, provided you do it as "high up" in your app as possible (like the app entry point file, which is usually called `app.js` or `server.js` or something).

Comment: When I do this, I get `"[ts] Cannot assign to 'Promise' because it is a constant or a read-only property."`

Answer (score 4):

For those of you using TypeScript, the correct way is:

`(<any>mongoose).Promise = YOUR_PROMISE;`

From the documentation:

```
Typescript does not allow assigning properties of imported modules. To avoid compile errors use one of the options below in your code:

(<any>mongoose).Promise = YOUR_PROMISE;

require('mongoose').Promise = YOUR_PROMISE;

import mongoose = require('mongoose'); mongoose.Promise = YOUR_PROMISE;

import mongoose from 'mongoose';
mongoose.Promise = mongoose;
```

Comment: Would you mind providing a link to the documentation you mention?  Thank you