# Node js mongoose promise attempt to assign to const or readonly variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, constants

It gives me the following error, is making the following assignment legal or is it a mistake?

[image: de]

```
import Promise from 'bluebird'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { mongo } from '../../config.js'

Object.keys(mongo.options || { }).forEach((key) => {
  mongoose.set(key, mongo.options[key])
})

mongoose.Promise = Promise
/* istanbul ignore next */
mongoose.Types.ObjectId.prototype.view = function () {
  return { id: this.toString() }
}

/* istanbul ignore next */
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err)
  process.exit(-1)
})

export default mongoose
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way of using Bluebird for Mongoose promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551550/what-is-the-correct-way-of-using-bluebird-for-mongoose-promises)

Comment: @Wex No, that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: What exactly is giving you that warning, a linter? TypeScript? Something else integrated into your IDE?